# Flexão de palavras em artigos - gênero masculino ou feminino?

Tags: concordância-nominal

Lendo o texto a seguir observei que e a autora usa o gênero feminino, mas ela não está escrevendo somente para mulheres. O mais comum é encontrar esse tipo de artigo no gênero masculino.

> **[O momento mais importante em sua vida](http://blogs.universal.org/cristianecardoso/pt/o-momento-mais-importante-em-sua-vida/)**
>
> *[...] A coisa mais importante sobre conquistar algo, é começar agora exatamente onde você está. “Faça o que puder, com o que você tem, onde você está.” Acredite em mim, você ficará **surpresa** com a maneira como você irá administrar as coisas.[...]*
>
> *[...] Se você sabe que agora é o momento mais importante, e, em seguida, no momento seguinte é o momento mais importante, e depois o próximo e assim por diante, você está muito mais **inclinada** a ser crítica com o uso de seu tempo. [...]*

Quando estamos escrevendo um texto para homens e/ou mulheres não seria mais adequado flexionar as palavras para o gênero masculino? Na língua inglesa pelo menos os artigo são curingas e parece simplificar essa questão de gênero.

Comment: Nesse caso específico, acredito que o objetivo da autora é direcionar o texto especificamente para mulheres. Aprendi no colégio que o correto é sempre usar o gênero masculino quando não se sabe quem irá ler, ou no caso de ter mais pessoas e uma delas ser masculino, usa-se também o genêro masculino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O gênero masculino é considerado neutro em português:

> Em português, os nomes são masculinos ou femininos – não existe o
>   chamado “gênero neutro”, salvo em algumas reminiscências latinas, como
>   os pronomes isto, isso e aquilo, por exemplo, que, para efeito de
>   concordância, são considerados masculinos. Na verdade, o gênero
>   masculino em português também expressa a ideia de neutralidade.

Fonte: [Dicas de Português - O gênero das Palavras](https://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/o-genero-das-palavras.jhtm)

Por outro lado, esse tipo de orientação pode parecer machista nos dias atuais, onde temos igualidade entre os gêneros (ou devíamos ter). Por isso, podemos até ao escrever, escolher palavras com gênero feminino, conforme o texto [Linguagem inclusiva de gênero em trabalho acadêmico](http://blogueirasfeministas.com/2013/08/linguagem-inclusiva-de-genero-em-trabalho-academico/).

No caso específico do texto citado, acredito que o objetivo da autora é se dirigir exclusivamente a mulheres, por isso, os gêneros no feminino.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, quando não se sabe o gênero do leitor do texto, deve-se fazer a concordância no masculino. Entretanto, o texto que você mencionou foi tirado de um blog com um público-alvo feminino, logo, é normal que o texto esteja no feminino, mesmo que haja leitores masculinos.